# Xamarin.Forms: How to properly use <OnPlatform> to pick which control to use in my TableSection?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `TableView` with few sections. In my `TableSection` I want to display different controls depending on the platform. I want to use the usual `TextCell` for iOS and a custom `ViewCell` for Android. I have tried the following code:

```
<TableSection Title="Activity">
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
      <On Platform="iOS">
         <TextCell x:Name="btnCountIOS" Text="Count" Height="50" />
         <TextCell x:Name="cardHistory" Text="History" StyleId="disclosure" Tapped="openHistoryPage" Height="50"/>
      </On>
      <On Platform="Android">
         <local:MyViewCell NoTap="true" Height="50">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
               <Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Today" />
               <Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="btnCountDroid" />
            </Grid>
         </local:MyViewCell>
         <local:MyViewCell>
            <!-- more code here -->
         </local:MyViewCell>
      </On>
   </OnPlatform>
</TableSection>
```

The above code does not work. It gives me an error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Am I missing something? Should I be using a different `x:TypeArguments`?

**Edit:**

Edited to incorporate @Fahadsk answer and now getting the error: `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.` Anyone knows why I'm getting this?

Comment: The problem with your code is that even though the property OnPlatform can return an array, it expects collection type directly. This is the perfect scenario where you would set the items from code behind.

Answer (score 7):

> OnPlatform is obsolete as of version 2.3.4.

Use following syntax in your code

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
     <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
     <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
</OnPlatform>
```

For more info on [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/) and this [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/658), also check out this [blog](https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have change it and now im getting a different error: `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.`

Comment: try to wrap your `OnPlatform` in `ContentView` as suggested in this post https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54366/control-only-on-one-platform-xaml-and-onplatform